How to cancel the F4 key on Ubuntu 22.04 (Wayland)
My laptop (thinkpad x1 carbon) is having some issues. One of them is that the F4 key is being pressed without me pressing it. I want to cancel that key. I tried xmodmap -e 'keycode 70=' but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?
